# Adding tags when creating new post

Tags: customization, tags, api

I am trying to create a new post with tags. Not having any luck and am not able to find any explanations online of what I may be doing wrong.

```
methods: {
  createPost: function() {

    let title = this.newPostTitle;
    let content = this.newPostContent;
    let postCategories = this.postCategories;
    let tags = this.newPostTags.split(",");

    let data = {
      'title': title,
      'content': content,
      'status': 'publish',
      'categories': postCategories,
      'tags': tags,
    };

    axios.post("/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/", data, {headers: {'X-WP-Nonce': portal.nonce}})
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e);
      console.log(this.errors);
    });

    this.newPostTitle = '';
    this.newPostContent = '';
    this.newPostTags = '';
    this.postCategories = false;
  }
}
```

I have the method property above to get the data and post it using VueJS and Axios. What do i need to do to get the tags to post correctly?

I keep getting the following error when I attempt to post

> "tags[0] is not of type integer."

Comment: Sounds like it's expecting a tag ID and you're sending a string.  `split` returns an array of strings, even if those strings are numbers.  instead of split try something like this:

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's expecting tag IDs as integers and you're sending strings.  `split` returns an array of strings, even if those strings are numbers.  Instead of using `.split` try something like this

```
let tags = JSON.parse("[" + this.newPostTags + "]");
```

If you really like split then you would do this:

```
let tags = this.newPostTags.split(",").map(Number);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually expecting a string of comma-separated concatenated tag ids (if anyone is still looking for an answer to this).

Your data would be something like the following, with your split code commented out:

```
let tags = this.newPostTags; // .split(",");
let data = {
  'title': title,
  'content': content,
  'status': 'publish',
  'categories': postCategories,
  'tags': tags,
};
```